# How do I organize my models when creating a 'changelog' that depends on old data?

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to make a changelog which will note **1) the date-time** an object is created/updated and **2) the objects themselves**(strings) over a long course of time.
Essentially, it "snapshots" the date-time along with the values of the objects at that specific time when `.save()` is called.

Here is an example changelog I'm attempting to display:

```
Oct. 24, 2017, 11:22 a.m  
"preference: bots", "preference: chocolate sundaes"  

Oct. 19, 2017, 12:04 p.m  
"preference: dogs", "preference: potatoes"  

Sep. 03, 2017, 01:22 a.m   
"preference: cats", "preference: cheese"
```

The example above shows *a single* `Changelog` of three updates, and a single `Changelog` belongs to a single `Profile` object.

What makes it difficult to establish is the fact that I'm not querying for the current date-time or objects' value, but all previous date-time and values must have persisted in the database to be displayed. Therefore, I thought I must create a model for not only the whole `Changelog` object, but also for the date-time, `CLDate`, and the objects, which I have called: `CLPreference`.
Including `Profile`, here are all four of the models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True, blank=True)
    main_preference = models.CharField(max_length=54, blank=True, null=True)
    secondary_preference = models.CharField(max_length=54, blank=True, null=True)

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_preferences(self):
        preferences = self.main_preference, self.secondary_preference
        return preferences


class Changelog(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(Profile)
    date_set = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    preference_set = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner


class CLDate(models.Model):
    date_owner = models.ForeignKey(Changelog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dates')
    date = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.date_owner


class CLPreference(models.Model):
    preference_owner = models.ForeignKey(Changelog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='preferences')
    preference = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.preference_owner
```

**Code explanation:** I'm not sure if this is a good way, but after drawing up the data tables, this seemed to be possible. I figured eventually, using for-loops and reverse relationships, I'd access the `CLDate` and `CLPreference` datasets to list out their values.

As far as actually instantiating things, I have attempted it using post-save signals:

```
def profile_post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance:
        o, created = Changelog.objects.get_or_create(owner=instance)

        d = CLDate(date_owner=instance, date=instance.timestamp)
        d.save()
        p = CLPreference(preference=instance.get_preferences())
        p.save()
post_save.connect(profile_post_save_receiver, sender=Profile)
```

**Code Explanation:** This fails immediately after the `if`--the `Changelog` object cannot be created due to `CLDate` and `CLSkill` not existing in the database. As you can now see, I had tried to use the `Profile` model's method, `get_preferences()` in order to save it to the model `CLPreference` while using the instance's `timestamp` to get the current time when it's being `save()`'ed.

I have drawn this out and tried hooking it up in various ways but I cannot seem to overcome this. Please advise--on the structure of the models, the controller aspect, or anything else that may get it working. I am open to any method.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the concepts of `ContentType` and `GenericForeignKey` to achieve this. The upside of using this is that you end up creating a single Changelog table which can hold changelogs for any other model, together in one table.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class GenericChangelog(models.Model):

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    data = models.TextField()
```

Your `Profile` table is assigned a content type id. While querying, use that id to query something like `GenericChangelog.objects.filter(object_id=99999, content_type_id=1).order_by('-created_on')` (assuming your Profile content type id is 1). This will return in descending order the object history.

Populating this change log can be done from a standard post-save receiver. To find and set the content type id, you can use `ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)`
Also, a shortcut to generate a quick JSON from a model object is to use the `model_to_dict` function available from `from django.forms.models import model_to_dict`